# Making multiple 'game screens' using Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

How would you be able to create multiple screens using Pygame and events performed by the user?

For example, if I had a menu screen with 2 buttons ('Start' and 'Exit') and the user clicked on 'Start', a new screen would appear in the same window with whatever is next in the game. From that screen, a user could click on another button and move on to another screen/ return to the menu, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make classes for each one, where each class is a subclass of pygame.Surface, of the same size as the display.  Then you could have 3 variable TITLESCREEN, PLAYING, HIGHSCORES and change them on key press.  Then you would be able to blit the correct screen to the display.

Answer (score 2):

It is same as with any program/language, you simply trigger current loop.
Consider this example:

```
FPS = 25
MainLoop = True
Loop1 = True         # Start app in Loop1
Loop2 = False        # Loop2 is idle 

while MainLoop :
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.event.pump()
    keypress = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    keypress_dn  = tuple(x > y for x,y in zip(keypress, keypress_old))
    keypress_old = keypress
    if Loop1:
        if keypress_dn [pygame.K_ESCAPE] :
            Loop1 = False
            MainLoop = False
        if keypress_dn [pygame.K_2] :   # goto Loop2
            Loop1 = False
            Loop2 = True 
        ...

    if Loop2:
        if keypress_dn [pygame.K_ESCAPE] :
            Loop2 = False
            MainLoop = False
        if keypress_dn [pygame.K_1] :   # goto Loop1
            Loop2 = False
            Loop1 = True 
        ... 

    pygame.display.flip( )

pygame.quit( )
```

So you add your rendering and check keypresses in corresponding loop. Here you press "2" to go to loop2 and press "1" to go to loop 1. "Escape" will quit both loops and main loop.

Answer (score 0):

What I did for this was have a literal main loop that checks to see what "Screen" the player wants to go to. Like if they press the exit button, it returns where to go next. The main loop then runs a the new script for the new screen.